# Can AUHAL adjust its I/O buffer size automatic?

Tags: c++, macos, core-audio, voip, audiounit

I'm using the `Audio Unit Framework` to develop a VOIP app on mac os x. There are two audio unit in my program , one is the input-only AUHAL ,the other is the default output unit.

I use the `input-only AUHAL` to capture audio. When the sample rate is `44.1khz` , in the AUHAL's callback , the value of `inNumberFrames` is `512` which means my program will get `512 frames` audio data from each call `AudioUnitRender`. And the value of `inNumberFrames` in the `default output unit's callback` is also `512`.In this case , every things is fine.

But when I change the sample rate(8khz) both on the `input-only AUHAL` and  `default output unit` , my program isn't working properly.

Because in the output unit's callback , the value of `inNumberFrames` became `93` which means the output device need `93 frames` audio data from each call , but the value of `inNumberFrames` remain `512` in the `AUHAL's` callback. The number of frames didn't match between the `AUHAL` and the `output unit` .

I can change the `AUHAL I/O buffer size` manual by using `AudioUnitSetProperty` and slove this problem by using a simple formula with a little error . But I want to know if there are some method to make the `AUHAL` adjust its I/O buffer size automatic just like the `default output unit` do ？

Thanks & regard